# shell script for loop is breaking lines?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

i am trying to hold some data of $i variable using cut command in another variable like ip and port number so that i can store both ip and port into database but this output creating issue to hold data due to next line please help..

```
foo=( $(grep logs  data.txt) ) 

    for i in "${foo[@]}"
    do

    echo "$i" | sed 's/Failed//g' | sed "s/logs//g" | sed "s/for//g" | sed "s/delmum//g" | sed "s/from//g"  | sed "s/port//g"  | sed "s/invalid//g" | sed "s/user//g"| sed "s/castis//g" | sed "s/guest//g" | sed '/^$/d'

    done

    Output :-Mar
    4
    03:08:15
    sshd[96487]:
    225.33.58.96
    62445

    Mar
    4
    03:08:15
    sshd[65741]:
    225.33.58.96
    62445

    Mar
    4
    03:08:15
    sshd[34595]:
    202.83.52.11
    43321

    Mar
    4
    03:08:16
    sshd[25485]:
    356.214.857.246
    12445

    Mar
    4
    03:08:16
    sshd[25245]:
    324.684.723.857
    24875


    output expected :- 
    Mar 4 03:08:15 sshd[96487]: 225.33.58.96 62445
    Mar 4 03:08:15 sshd[34595]: 202.83.52.11 43321
    Mar 4 03:08:16 sshd[25245]: 324.684.723.857 24875

data.txt
Mar  4 03:08:15 delmum sshd[96487]: Failed logs for root from 225.33.58.96 port 62445 ssh2
Mar  4 03:08:06 perfmum sshd[33799]: Connection closed by
Mar  4 03:08:15 delmum sshd[65741]: Failed logs for root from 225.33.58.96 port 62445 ssh2
Mar  4 03:08:15 delmum sshd[34595]: Failed logs for root from 202.83.52.11 port 43321 ssh2
Mar  4 03:08:06 delmum sshd[12485]: Connection closed by
Mar  4 03:08:06 delmum sshd[85468]: Connection closed by
Mar  4 03:08:06 delmum sshd[51396]: Connection closed by
Mar  4 03:08:16 delmum sshd[25485]: Failed logs for invalid user castis from 356.214.857.246 port 12445 ssh2
Mar  4 03:08:16 delmum sshd[25245]: Failed logs for invalid user castis from 324.684.723.857 port 24875 ssh2
Mar  4 03:08:06 delmum sshd[23541]: Connection closed by
```

data.txt content in line but why loop breaking the line its self

Comment: How is original data formatted?

Comment: Not an answer but you can put all those sed commands into a single command and separate each one by `;`, it will be much more efficient.

Comment: Also it's separating because you are using `for i in` which separates on white space. Use `while read` instead.

Comment: i have added data.txt file  greping data from data.txt

Comment: @Vijay, I have provided you a solution which is working in my system. Please try with that.

Comment: Both `sed` and `awk` by default loop through the lines of their input.  If you ever find yourself feeding individual lines to sed instead of letting it read the data itself, you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: And by "probably", I mean "almost certainly".  And by "almost" I mean "". That is, you can omit "almost".  You're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

With single **`awk`** command:

```
awk '/logs/{ 
         if (/from/ && /port/) { sub(/: .* from/,""); tail=":" OFS $6 OFS $8 }
         print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5 tail; tail=""; 
     }' data.txt
```

Sample output:

```
Mar 4 03:08:15 delmum sshd[96487]: 225.33.58.96 62445
Mar 4 03:08:15 delmum sshd[65741]: 225.33.58.96 62445
Mar 4 03:08:15 delmum sshd[34595]: 202.83.52.11 43321
Mar 4 03:08:16 delmum sshd[25485]: 356.214.857.246 12445
Mar 4 03:08:16 delmum sshd[25245]: 324.684.723.857 24875
```

Answer (score 0):

You can process the whole log line by line without reading each line into a variable:

```
grep logs  data.txt \
| sed 's/Failed\|logs\|for\|delmum\|from\|port\|invalid\|user\|castis\|guest//g'
```

It's also much faster to run just one `sed` instead of many, and to use just one expression rather than many in it.

Comment: If you are minimising why not just scrap grep.

Comment: ip = echo "$i" | sed 's/Failed;//g' | sed "s/logs//g" | sed "s/for//g" | sed "s/delmum//g" | sed "s/from//g"  | sed "s/port//g" | sed "s/perfmum//g" | sed "s/invalid//g" | sed "s/user//g"| sed "s/castis//g" | sed "s/guest//g" | sed '/^$/d'
                                                                                                   
 mysql --user=$DB_USER --password=$DB_PASSWD $DB_NAME -e "INSERT INTO $TABLE (ip, port) VALUES ('${ip}','${port}')"                        i want to store this ip and port into database

Comment: how to grep only ip and store in the database @choroba

Comment: @Vijay: If you want to ask a new question, create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

it is working for me:-

```
 grep logs  data.txt > tmp.txt
 while read -r line
 do
    echo "$line" | sed 's/Failed//g;s/logs//g;s/for//g;s/delmum//g;s/from//g;s/port//g;s/invalid//g;s/user//g;s/castis//g;s/guest//g;/^$/d;s/ssh2//g;s/root//g;s/  */ /g' > ./sort.txt
 done < ./tmp.txt

 rm ./tmp.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

with sed

```
sed -E '
/logs/!d
h
s/.*from ([^ ]*) .*port ([^ ]*).*/\1 \2/
x
s/(.*:).*/\1/;s/([^ ]* )//5
G
y/\n/ /
' data.txt
```